# How to examine source code of Firefox extension before installing it?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there a convenient way to examine the source code for a Firefox extension before installing it?

(There is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-gallery-and-web/bbamfloeabgknfklmgbpjcgofcokhpia) that offers this functionality, though I have not used it, and cannot say how well it works.  At any rate, I am interested primarily in Firefox extensions.)

Comment: Is http://www.instructables.com/id/Extract-Firefox-Addon-Source-Code/ still relevant? It's very dated.

Comment: @JasonC: It is, Firefox add-ons are still regular ZIP files that can be easily unpacked.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To check a Firefox extension source before installing. This works on macos and linux.

1. Got to e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-same-tab/
2. Right click "+ Add to Firefox" and "Copy Link Location"

[image: Screenshot of Firefox showing "Copy Link Location" menu item]

3. Download and unpack the copied url:

```
$ curl -L https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/3570442/open_same_tab-0.1.7-fx.xpi?src=dp-btn-primary > /tmp/extension.xpi
$ unzip /tmp/extension.xpi -d /tmp/extension
```

The extension source is now in `/tmp/extension`.

4. To install if you're happy with the review, open `file:///tmp/extension.xpi` in Firefox.

Answer (score 16):

As [Wladimir pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/771825/how-to-examine-source-code-of-firefox-extension-before-installing-it?rq=1#comment1002473_771825) the .xpi file is simply a ZIP archive put together in a particular way. Open it with WinRAR, 7-zip or rename it to .zip and open it with your OS's default tool.

EDIT:
*(It appears that Mozilla's [addons](https://addons.mozilla.org) page no longer has this type of "Install" button, so this method won't work.)*
<del>To get ahold of the .xpi file use https://addons.mozilla.org instead of the built-in extension manager. From there you can right-click on the install button and choose `Save as...`</del>

With *installed* extensions, you can:

1. [open your Firefox profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)
2. double-click the `extensions` subfolder
3. identify the `.xsi` file of the desired extension (some are obvious, others not)
4. right-click on the `.xsi` file and choose `Open With` (and then possibly `More Apps`)
5. choose your zip file management app (ie. [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm), [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html), etc) and the extension should open as a compressed folder.

Comment: The button is there as of March 2021.